# Change datetime weekday without going back in time

Tags: python, datetime

How do I set the weekday for the provided datetime  object without looping back in time?

This is how I first did it

```py
now = dt.datetime.now() # February 18
target_weekday = 2 # Wednesday next week
future = ((now - dt.timedelta(days=now.weekday())) + dt.timedelta(days=target_weekday))
```

This outputs this week's wednesday which is February 16 (In the past)
What I want is for it to output next week's wednesday, not all the time though, it only has to move to next week if the provided `target_weekday` is in the past. But if the weekday is let's say `5`, then it would just add an extra day

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please be more concise and clear when asking questions. In order making it concise and clear, you may need to add more detailed explanations about what you actually want to achieve, what's your current program do, and what went wrong from it. Also, adding some examples would be better as it make people having better understanding to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to figure out a solution that works all the time

```py
def construct_next(weekday: int, datetime: dt.datetime) -> dt.datetime:
    if weekday == datetime.weekday():
        return datetime + dt.timedelta(days=7)
    elif weekday > datetime.weekday():
        return datetime + dt.timedelta(days=weekday - datetime.weekday())
    return ((datetime - dt.timedelta(days=datetime.weekday())) + dt.timedelta(days=weekday + 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be checked if the target weekday is in the past or future and add days according to that in timedelta

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
target_weekday = 5
result = now + dt.timedelta(
  days=(7 - target_weekday if now.weekday() > target_weekday else target_weekday - now.weekday()))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately this gives thursday when set to 1. I was ablle to figure out a solution myself (see accepted solution)